# Getting [-] ERROR Could not synchronize database state with session : org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener-(277)

Tags: hibernate, environment

I am getting the below error :

```
[-] ERROR Could not synchronize database state with session : org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener-(277)
```

We have the same code deployed on various environments and we are facing the above error in one particular environment only therefore it doesn't seem like a code issue.
Any pointers will be helpful.
Hibernate Version: 3.0.4
Env: Unix Box.

Please find the below logs:

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update: 0 actual row count: 0 expected: 1
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCount(BatchingBatcher.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:78)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:174)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:226)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:730)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:324)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:86)



 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
[-] ERROR Could not synchronize database state with session : org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener-(277)
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update: 0 actual row count: 0 expected: 1
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCount(BatchingBatcher.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:78)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:174)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:226)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:730)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:324)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:86)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of the stale data. 
There are 2 possible solutions.

1.) Check your code for usage of @Tansaction annotation if at all you are using it. If you are using it, try to change the propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW. If you are not using this annotation, try option 2.

2.) Add cascade='save-update'

Comment: But then how is the same code working in other environment(spring profiles).

Comment: different CPUs have different clock cycles to synchronize the events. Just to keep the answer short. What was the outcome? Did you try the solution?

Comment: no solution has been found yet, cannot make the code changes as it is working in other environments. The only difference among the env's are the version of oracle DB. The one with Oracle 10g is working and one with Oracle 12c isn't. Can it be DB compatibility issue ?

Comment: Yes it can be the DB compatibility issue. It's just a matter of trial and error. Change the DB version to the version in which your code is working. Check it out and you will have the result.